# 8051 most time efficient way to recognise a sequence

Tags: performance, clock, processing-efficiency, 8051

I have an 8051 receiving an external interrupt. In the ISR I have to read the state of a pin1 and do the following:

- If pin1 is high and was high the previous interrupt and if pin2 is low --> Set pin2 high
- If pin1 is low and was low the previous interrupt and if pin2 is high --> set pin2 low

If i keep receiving n ones or n zeroes, i don't want to call the function to set pin2 because it's already in the right state.
If i receive something like 11 (here i set pin 2 high) 1010101111 I don't want to set pin2 again on the second 11 sequence.
This is because setting pin2 takes time and don't have time to waste doing something I don't need to do.

I'm using a custom variant of the 8051 with external data memory so it takes 2 MOV and a MOVX to write to the pins I'm talking about.

My goal is to minimize the clock cycles needed to implement the function described above. I was going for state machine implemented through a LUT, but I'm wondering if it's the fastest way to do this and, if it is, what is the best method to implement the LUT and the state machine.

I can code the function in C or assembly (only if extremely necessary).

Answer (score 0):

You can use bit-operations to get this done.

A conditional jump checking a bit takes longer than setting or clearing a (port) bit. Your assumption about "wasting time" is wrong here.

Therefore a combinatorial solution seems promising.

1. Pin2 shall become 0, if the current and the old value of pin1 are 0.
2. Pin2 shall keep its value, if any of the current and the old value of pin1 is 1.
3. Pin2 shall become 1, if the current and the old value of pin1 are 1.

```c
sbit pin1 = ...;
sbit pin2 = ...;

static bit pin1_old;

void ISR(void) {
    bit pin1_current = pin1;
    pin2 = ((pin1_current | pin1_old) & pin2) | (pin1_current & pin1_old);
    pin1_old = pin1_current;
}
```

Depending on your compiler you can put the static variable `pin1_old` inside the ISR to make it even more private.

If your pin2 might be driven low from the external circuitry when it is supposed to be high, you will need a shadow bit for it.

You might like to inspect the resulting assembly that it is actually well optimized. Depending on your compiler I would expect operations on `C` and/or `F0`.

**Addition:**

If your ports are memory-mapped and accessed via `MOVX`, you can still cache the value from the port of pin1 in a variable located in `bdata`. And then read from the bit of that variable.

To write pin2, you might already need a shadow variable for its port. Place this also in `bdata` to speed up the access to pin2.

To further save some cycles, consider to use `pdata` accesses for the memory-mapped ports. The instructions `MOVX A,@DPTR` and `MOVX A,@R0` (or R1) use an equal number of cycles. But loading `DPTR` takes longer than loading `R0`. You can preload `P2` during start-up and leave it untouched in operation.

Comment: What if my pins are not bit addressable with SFR registers? and it takes 4 clock cycles to write the value to the register?

Comment: Then add this important information to your question, please. You should mention the derivative you are using, together with the ports and pins. -- There are only two instructions that use 4 cycles, `DIV` and `MUL`. All other instructions use 1 or 2 cycles. And no, copying a bit from a port pin to a bit variable needs just 3 cycles, because of the two bit-wise moves `MOV C,pin` and `MOV bit,C` using 1 and 2 cycles, respectively. See the assembly listing and the programmer's manual.

Comment: You are right, I should have explained it in the question. I'm using a custom variant with external data memory so it takes 2 MOV and a MOVX to write to the pins I'm talking about.